# UseSelector for same value name from different states

Tags: javascript, redux

I successfully get my uid from the sandboxKey like this:

```
const { uid } = useSelector((state) => state.apikeys.sandboxKey);
```

I also need the uid from the prodkey as well:

```
const { uid } = useSelector((state) => state.apikeys.prodKey);
```

How can I seperate them? I get uid has already been declared

This is the full code

```
const createSandboxKey = async () => {

    const newSandbox ={};

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };

    await axios
      .put(
        `/api/v1/key/new-sandbox-keys/${uid}`,
        newSandbox,
        config
      )

const createProdKey = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newProd ={};

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };

    await axios
      .put(
        `/api/v1/key/new-prod-keys/${uid}`,
        newProd,
        config
      )
```